# Send PHP Multidimensional Array to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, wordpress

I'm working on Wordpress. I Got a Php array like this:

```
$listDates[x]['start_date'] = '00:00 12-04-2017';  // Example dates
$listDates[x]['end_date'] = '00:05 22-05-2018';
...
$list_allDates = json_encode($listDates);
```

And then, I want to send this to JS/JQuery some good way that works... I tried all I saw on stackoverflow and another websites...

My JS code receives with something like this right now (last way I tried) :

```
var multidate_array = JSON.parse('<?php $list_allDates; ?>');
```

Gives me this error :

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input** on JS Code...

Some Idea? :(

Comment: `$list_allDates !== $all_dates_list`

Comment: And `JSON.parse` is not needed as `$list_allDates` __already__ a json.

Comment: `var multidate_array = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($listDates) ?>');`

Comment: `$listDates !== $list_dates`

Comment: I corrected it on edition. I wrote all code manually, in reality all in original code is well written

Answer (score 0):

Assing json_encode to your js_array:

```
<?php 
$phpArray[0][0] = 0;
$phpArray[0][1] = 1;
$phpArray[1][0] = 2;
$phpArray[1][1] = 3;
?>
<script>
var js_array = <?php echo json_encode($phpArray);?>;
console.log(js_array);
// [0][0] = 0;
// [0][1] = 1;
// [1][0] = 2;
// [1][1] = 3;
</script>
```